# Ruby on Rails realtime activity notification

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, websocket

I'm trying to implement a feature that let's a user know about the activity of other users over certain page, for example, let's suppose we have a blog, and users can edit blog posts, I'd like that when a user enters the edit page for a specific post then a message is displayed saying "User1, User2, ..., UserN are editing this post too".

The easiest way to implement this would be that when a user enters the edit page (a thing we can know based on what controller action we are rendering) then we store this data on some kind of memory (is Rails.cache a good choice for this?), and when the user leaves the page we remove that record from the memory (a solution for this could be using the onunload event handler, but this is not useful for my case because it skips several cases, and also i'm using AJAX which implies that i don't unload my whole DOM).
On the other hand i thought of using web sockets or Faye.. but well, let's keep it short and go straight to the point:
I want it to be as "real time" as possible, which means, 
I'm on the edit page, initially a message might be displayed if some users are already editing the page, when a new one comes to edit the same post it should be added to the message, and if one leaves the edit page this should be removed from the edit page...for that the concrete questions are:

1. What kind of memory would you use in Rails to keep this information, or would you use Faye + subscribe/unsubscribe to channel event handler?
2. How can a user say 3 things: "Hey server, i'm on the page", "Hey server, I'm still on the page" and "Hey server, I'm leaving this page".

Thank you guys in advance for your help!

P/D: I'm usign Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax requests with [Redis](http://redis.io).

You can set a key in redis with a [expiration date](http://redis.io/commands/expire), and with ajax you are renewing the expiration date, if the user closes the tab, the key will expire and you consider that the user is no longer editing.

Hope it helps